# Why is ng-content removing the rest of my content?

Tags: angular, transclusion

Starting my first Angular 2 app, and I'm trying to get <ng-content> to work, however, it's doing strange things...

My main.ts:

```
import { bootstrap } from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [])
    .then(success => console.log('Bootstrap success'))
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: '/app/app.component.html'
})

export class AppComponent {
}
```

and app.component.html:

```
<div class="container-fluid contentArea">
    Test before
    <ng-content></ng-content>
    Test after
</div>
```

In my index.html, I have this:

```
<my-app>
    Test
</my-app>
```

What happens is that I see

```
Test Before Test After
```

for about 2 seconds until Angular bootstraps, then it clears the page and I see only

```
Test
```

What am I doing wrong here and how do I keep the Test Before Test After on my page?

Answer (score 1):

Transclusion on the root component is not supported. This works only within component templates but not from `index.html` to a component.

Comment: So how would I accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: If you want to project content from the `index.html` to a component, then I guess you are out of luck. Otherwise just move `<my-app>
    Test
</my-app>` into a component.